# Is there any situation when the haftarah of Tetzaveh might be read during a non-leap year?

Tags: calendar, haftarah, four-parshiot

This past Shabbat, we read the *haftarah* of *Tetzaveh*. If I have calculated correctly, I don't think there is any situation where this *haftarah* would be read during a non-leap year. I think that *Tetzaveh* would always be *parshat Zachor* in a non-leap year.

Am I correct, or have I missed something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A counterexample:

In 5781, Tetzavveh will be read on Shabbat 15 Adar and locations not celebrating Shushan Purim will read the ordinary Haftarah.

Comment: Is there a case in which the Haftarah is read *everywhere*?

Comment: @Doniel I think only in leap years. The listed example is very rare. It's only when Pesach starts Sunday (rarest day) so there's an extra Shabbat before Pesach and only in a "Chaser" year so the previous Rosh Hashana was on Shabbat so Vayakhel is joined with Pekudei after Tetzavveh is read. That's only 6.9% of non leap years.